# Segfault when non-sudo

Tags: linux, fedora, segmentation-fault

For some weird reason, several programs have started to segfault when I try to run them without escalated privileges. Among these are `gnome-abrt` and `variety` which used to run fine *without* `sudo` up until yesterday; if I run them *with* `sudo` they work fine. I still haven't figured out if there are other applications that have the same issues but I am guessing that if I find out what is causing it for one of the applications, it will solve it for all of them.

The output I get from running e.g. `gnome-abrt` in the terminal is:

```bsh
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** running `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME && sudo restorecon -r $HOME` seems to have created unexpected changes. Opening up Steam gives me this error:

```bsh
Repairing installation, linking /home/myuser/.steam/steam to /home/myuser/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove '/home/myuser/.steam/steam': Permission denied
Setting up Steam content in /home/myuser/.local/share/Steam
ln: failed to access '/home/myuser/.steam/steam': Permission denied
```

Please help me "undo" this command.

**EDIT 2:** those two particular packages were updated today, so it seems that something has gone wrong on the devs' end.

Comment: Linux distro? Version of the distro? Are the packages up to date?

Comment: Fedora 34 and, yes, everything is up-to-date. When I opened `abrt` (using `sudo`)  and tried to report several of the issues, it told me that there was 'too little valuable .information'

Comment: @Artem in those commands the variables are expanded by the shell before `sudo` sees them ;-).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried both with variables and whole paths and user but they didn't work :/

Comment: Ok, I tried opening up a random program now and it seems that something else happened. Please check my edit.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `id`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),10(wheel),135(mock) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

Comment: please run this: `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser`

Comment: Sorry for the first command :( Hopefully everything will now be fixed

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That's what I did the second time, when the one with the variables didn't seem to work, but I rebooted after execution (both times). Should I reboot or not? Also, it's okay, I have a cron job set up to take backups of anything important and I plan on doing a fresh install when F35 comes out :) It would be nice to have a working system in the meantime, though x)

Comment: After the second proper command do you still have issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130321/discussion-between-artem-s-tashkinov-and-telometto).

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov variable expansion comes before command execution.

Comment: @D4RIO What does that mean? How should I execute the command?

Comment: Looks like the issue is caused by some recent updates.

Comment: It doesn't mean something to you. BTW, you should report this bug ASAP to the maintainers.

Comment: @D4RIO Will do. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the shared libraries (`*.so`) used by the failing programs has probably had its permissions changed.

Compare the results of

```
sudo ldd $(type -p programname)
# and
ldd $(type -p programname)
```

Comment: I tried `ldd $(type -p gnome-abrt)` both with and without `sudo` and both times it yields `not a dynamic executable`.

Comment: `gnome-abrt` is a python application. It's not that easy to follow its dependencies.